# Infinite intersection non-empty if finite intersections are non-empty proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $ A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_n \neq \emptyset $ for all  $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Is it also true that $ A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \neq \emptyset$ ?

I'm guessing no, could I have a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No definitely not. Consider the sequence of sets $(0, 1/n) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then clearly $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,1/n) = \varnothing$$ Since if $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(0,1/n)$, we have $$0 < x < 1/n$$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since limits preserve inequalities, we would have $$0 < x \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Try $A_n = \{k\in \Bbb N: k \ge n\}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sets
$$
A_n = \{x \ |\ 0<x<\frac{1}{n}\}
$$
so that $A_m\subset A_n \ \forall \ m>n$.
We have that 
$$
\begin{align}
A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n =& A_n\\
\neq&\emptyset
\end{align}
$$
but
$$
\begin{align}
A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots =&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n\\
=& \{x \ |\ 0<x<0\} \\
=&\emptyset
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one:  Let $A_n$ be the set of integers divisible by $n$.  Then for any finite collection of sets of the form $A_k$, the intersection consists of integers divisible by every subscript -- in other words integers divisible by the least common multiple of the subscripts.  So it's nonempty.  But the intersection of *all* of the sets is empty, because no integers is divisible by *everything*.